# Promise chaining + return variable with meteor callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise

How can I achieve below?

server side:

execute bash commands to generate files. then return the path of file D

```
const exec = Meteor.isServer ? require('child_process').exec : undefined;

Meteor.methods({
  createFile_D(){
    const BashCommand_A = `generate file A`;
    const BashCommand_B = `generate file B, using file A`;
    const BashCommand_C = `generate file C, using file B`;
    const BashCommand_D = `generate file D, using file C`;

    const runCommand = function (cmd) {
      let command = exec(cmd, path);
      command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
      });
      command.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
      });
      command.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
        resolve('done');
      })
    }

    // execute BashCommand A ~ D
    // when it's all done return the path of file D

  } 
});
```

client side:

retrieve path of generated file D as a callback of Meteor.call

```
Meteor.call('createFile_D', function (error, result) {
  if(error || (result === undefined)) {
    throw error;
  } else {
    do_something_with_result (result);
  }
});
```

Comment: how/where is `runCommand` executed?

Comment: I can get you this far [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mecfxogz/) unfortunately I don't know Meteor well enough to know what to do at this point :p

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync) or Async/Await:

```
const runCommand = (cmd) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Make sure `path` variable is exists
    let command = exec(cmd, path);
    command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });
    command.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });
    command.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
      resolve(path);
    })
  });
};

Meteor.methods({
  async createFile_D(){
    const BashCommand_A = `generate file A`;
    const BashCommand_B = `generate file B, using file A`;
    const BashCommand_C = `generate file C, using file B`;
    const BashCommand_D = `generate file D, using file C`;


    await runCommand(BashCommand_A);
    await runCommand(BashCommand_B);
    await runCommand(BashCommand_C);
    const path_D = await runCommand(BashCommand_D);

    // path_D from resolve() in Promise
    return path_D;
  } 
});
```

Read more info on await / async